# Как менять символы в консоли не меняя строки?

Tags: c#, .net

Вот отсчет простым циклом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать что бы отсчет был в одной строке и менялось только число
Готовность %number% %
Где number менялось бы на 1,3,4.... и при этом слово Готовность не писалось бы повторно.

Comment: Оставлю это здесь: `Console.Write($"\rГотовность {i}%");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться методом [Console.SetCursorPosition(Int32, Int32)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=netcore-3.1)

```
Console.WriteLine("Important String");
Console.Write("Same line -> ");
Console.Write("Ready: ");
            
int left = Console.CursorLeft;
int top = Console.CursorTop;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
    Console.Write($"{i} %");
}
```

Преимущество этого подхода над простой очисткой экрана в том, что вы не теряете информацию о предыдущих действиях иих результатах:

[image: Результат работы]

Answer (score 0):

После каждого вывода на консоль очищать её.
Console.Clear();

Comment: А если в консоли что-то есть, что не надо очищать?